# SQL JOIN or UNION or what?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I have 3 tables named A, B and C. Table A have column a. Table B has column a, b. Table C has column a, c. These tables contains data like below:

[image]

I want to get all data from A,B,C where a=1

My desired output should look like below:

[image]

But I'm getting result from SSMS like below:

[image]

How should I refactor my SQL to get my desired output?

**e.g. I don't want repeated values in columns**

Comment: *"I don't want repeated values in columns"* You want a very unusual thing and I'd argue that it is between hard and impossible to create your desired output in SQL. Can you explain what data you are operating on, how exactly it is related and why this particular output format must be the result of an SQL query?

Comment: @Tomalak please have a look at my accepted answer from **@Gordon Linoff**. May be that was **hard**. But **impossible** ?

Comment: "impossible" depends on the database server used. And you did not answer my questions. I'm really wondering what all this is for. to me this looks like a DB design error and general abuse of the relational database paradigm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join these values, but not only on the `a` value but on the position.  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  I am going to assume that the `b` and `c` columns represent the ordering.

```
select a.a, b.b, c.c
from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by a) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a full outer join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.a = b.a and a.seqnum = b.seqnum full outer join
     (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by a order by c) as seqnum
      from c
     ) c
     on c.a = coalesce(a.a, b.a) and c.seqnum = coalesce(a.seqnum, b.seqnum)
where coalesce(a.a, b.a, c.a) = 1;
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit about your query! **And what if I do not have ordering in b and c columns?**

Comment: @autopilot . . . I'm not sure what needs to be explained.  The subqueries add a sequential number to each table for the "a" values.  This sequential number is then used as part of conditions for a `full outer join`, which keeps all rows from both tables, even when there is no match.